# Using template metaprogramming in C++, find the GCD of two integers

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, greatest-common-divisor

I want to know a **template meta-programming** solution to the problem of finding the GCD of two numbers using  using the recursive Euclid's Algorithm, given below for your reference.

```
function gcd(a, b)
    if b = 0
       return a; 
    else
       return gcd(b, a mod b);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for code, with no demonstrated effort to provide code that addresses the problem.   The OP will learn more by working out a solution, than in being spoon-feed one.

Comment: @Peter  I find this kind of closure really frustrating.   I'm here looking for an answer to this question in order to avoid reinventing the wheel; it seems likely that the question closure has prevented good answers from surfacing.  Luckily, in this case, it looks like a good answer was posted before the closure.

Comment: @DonHatch - I don't make the guidelines here - if you want to argue that the criteria for closing questions should change, there is always Meta.   Also, I was only one of five people who voted for closure before the question was closed - it's not something I did unilaterally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this?

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<int a, int b> struct gcd
{
    static constexpr auto value = gcd<b, a % b>::value;
};

template<int a>
struct gcd<a, 0>
{
    static constexpr auto value = a;
};

int main()
{
    auto x = gcd<10,5>::value;

    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: In the specialised version, why do you not say struct gcd<int a, 0>?

Comment: @VarunRao because that's not how template parameters are used. You don't write `printf(const char * "My Text");`

Comment: @VarunRao try it and see.